# html tags isn't recognized in source code

Tags: c#, html, webclient, downloadstring

I use a method in C# which download source code of website but the relevant html tag isn't there always. for example "<a href".

this is the method:

```
    public static string GetHTMLCodeByUrl(string url)
    {
        // Create web client.
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        // Download string.
        string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);

        return htmlCode;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Well, if the content isn't there then the content isn't there.  I guess you'd need to take that up with whoever runs that server.  This code just fetches the response, whatever that response is.

Comment: The missing tags could be generated by client side code and added dynamically.